# Fetching data from REST API based on the child subset attributes - Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have one REST API which returns all the parent and respective child (subsets - one or many subsets for each parent).There are one or more childObjects for each parentObject.

https://hostname//hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/parentObject?onlyData=true&expand=childObject&limit=1000

I want to know if there is a way to fetch the above records in GET operation by any of the attribute in childObject.
Let's say childObject has an attribute "Date", then we need to check for every parentObject if any of the childObject's "Date" attribute is less than the sysdate(currentDate) and "Date" attribute is not NULL. Then to fetch only those records instead of all the records.

Please guide us on how to add these conditions to the REST API in postman - may be some filter/query params/something else.

Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no answer to your question. It depends on the API. If you made the API yourself, you'll need to code it yourself. And if you're using another API, then just look at the docs, it should say if it's possible with their specific API or not. Postman is not magical, it won't "modify" APIs so that they can accept different parameters

Comment: Thanks Blex for your quick response. I am using another API, the docs are not clear on using this.I am just trying to understand in these scenarios how are we going to pass these parameters to the REST API? If there is way then I could check the same method on the REST API which I have. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, every API is different. Some follow some standards or use frameworks which enforce those standards _(and there are different ones)_ and others don't, and make it their own way. But by searching around, it looks like yours is following the [Oracle REST API Standard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/19d/farca/Resource_Methods.html). It looks like you can use the `q` parameter to filter parent Objects, but I'm not really sure about child Objects

Comment: Thank you Blex for your information.
Yeah we can use "q" parameter on parentObject to filter the response but was looking for anything similar for child objects.
Filtering parent objects with query parameter is straight forward, but the requirement is to filter the response based on the child objects attributes.